How do i solve this issue with my ugarch spec with exogenous regressors in R?
I am trying to run a garch(1,1)- with exogenous regressors. However I get a error in R
This first image shows my spec in r
enter image description here
I get the following mistake:
enter image description here
Does anyone know what I need to correct in order for me to define my spec?
I have looked at alt the help functions, but i cannot seem to figure out what i do wrong

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images. Explicitly list all non-base R packages you are using.

We don’t support images as a way to show code or text output. It prevents searching easily or testing code. Replace those links with text blocks and include code to build a working test case.
